# Le "touriste idiot" vs "cet idiot de touriste"

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

I was wondering how to formulate the following sentence in french:

> Above all she doesn't want to be the/that "idiotic tourist", a reputation that Americans sometimes have and that she hates.

Could I simply write:

> Elle ne veut surtout pas être "le touriste idiot", une réputation que les américains ont parfois et qu'elle déteste.

Or should I rather write:

> Elle ne veut surtout pas être "cet idiot de touriste"...

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would express it:

> Par dessus tout, elle ne veut pas être rangée dans la catégorie « touriste idiot » qu'on attribue parfois aux Américains et qu'elle déteste.